# Can a scanner exist on a PC using both ISIS and TWAIN drivers?

Tags: drivers, twain

Can TWAIN and ISIS drivers co-exist on a PC and cause no issues?

Answer (score 0):

Our program uses ISIS.  When we remote to user computers, often they have the TWAIN already running for other apps.  We load ISIS, load our program and seem to be okay.  We don't remove the TWAIN driver so it seems they can co-exist.  Now if you are asking about doing something like trying to have two devices in the OS using the different drivers, that I'm not sure about.

Comment: Our issue is that we have two seperate applications that require the two different drivers. At boot up ISIS is activated, thus causing issues when trying to scan from one application (from same devices). We are looking for a work around that we can use to allow both drivers to co-excist and allow for the applications to work without disabling either one.